# wpf make same control appear in two different places

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child, duplicate-data

in wpf, I have a canvas, that when double-clicked, needs to be opened in a separate tab for editing. when switching tabs, I need to be able to see the canvas in its original place, with the changes applied.
Is there a trick to make it the child of both TabItems? if no, is there anything else I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of ur requirement

Comment: The trick is called MVVM. Create a proper view model for your application, and when switching to edit mode, show an editable representation of your data.

Comment: most certainly! :) http://postimg.org/image/w7tns50ex/

Comment: You cannot have the same UI control with two different parents, it will thrown an exception (and rightly so). Just create a new instance of it, and ensure the data used to generate it is in a ViewModel so that it can be easily recreated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities :

- Use MVVM architecture, then you can bind the same data in different views.
- Change the parent property to your control.
- Clone the control.
- Use screenshots to fake a clone.

Exemple to take a screenshot of a control :

```
    public static BitmapSource SnapShotToBitmap(this UIElement source, double zoomX, double zoomY)
    {
        try
        {
            DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();

            double actualHeight = source.RenderSize.Height;
            double actualWidth = source.RenderSize.Width;

            if (actualHeight == 0)
                actualHeight = 1;
            if (actualWidth == 0)
                actualWidth = 1;

            double renderHeight = actualHeight * zoomY;
            double renderWidth = actualWidth * zoomX;

            RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)renderWidth, (int)renderHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(source);

            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            using (drawingContext)
            {
                drawingContext.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(zoomX, zoomY));
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(actualWidth, actualHeight)));
            }
            renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

            return renderTarget;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about faking a clone, but the canvas is still resizeable when it's in the layout (in the edit mode, I can add / remove and change buttons). so when resizing, it will stretch the the image, instead of giving extra space on the canvas.. is the MVVM thing difficult to do? can it be done for this only, or do I need to shape the entire program accordingly? thanks!

Comment: -1 *I have a canvas, that when double-clicked, needs to be opened in a separate tab for editing*... how would you do that with a screen shot?

Comment: I just listed the methods i know to duplicate visualy an element.

Comment: @user3491573 No. Mvvm is not a difficult thing to do. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM Solution to this would be rather easy.

```
public class KeyboardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ToolItemViewModel> _toolItems;

    public ObservableCollection<ToolItemViewModel> ToolItems
    {
        get { return _toolItems; }
        set
        {
            _toolItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ToolItems");
        }
    }

    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ToolItemViewModel AddToolItem()
    {
        ToolItemViewModel item = new ToolItemViewModel();
        ToolItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }
}

public class ToolItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _tooltip;

    public string Tooltip
    {
        get { return _tooltip; }
        set
        {
            _tooltip = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tooltip");
        }
    }


    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Basically somewhere in your code you can pass an instance of what you are working with as argument and any view working with that instance will be synchronized.

MVVM is something you really should learn, in order to work efficiently with WPF.

Comment: Thanks! I'll now try it! :) you are wonderful people and I'm so glad this place exists!

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to have a look into DataTemplates with this since you'll be working with TabControl/ItemsControl/ListView a lot. I wish i started off learning MVVM immediately when i began with WPF. It makes things so much easier once you're used to it. Good luck! Don't forget to mark helpful answers btw :)